# Retrieving Bitmap of View results in cropped image

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to retrieve a Bitmap of a View, in essence a screenshot. My current implementation goes as follows:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v)
{
   Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getHeight(), v.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
   v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
   v.draw(c);

   return b;
}
```

Yet, for some reason, I'm getting some issues with retrieving the whole View. The result image is cropped, leaving some parts cut off. At first, I thought it was a problem with the layout settings, as I had set width to `fill_parent`, but the problem persisted when I set it to `300dp`.

Answer (score 0):

**MY contributing ->**

[ACTIVITY MAIN]

```
            //ADD PACKAGE HERE

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.graphics.Bitmap;
            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.provider.MediaStore;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            /**
             * ShootAndCropActivity demonstrates capturing and cropping camera images
             * - user presses button to capture an image using the device camera
             * - when they return with the captured image Uri, the app launches the crop action intent
             * - on returning from the crop action, the app displays the cropped image
             * 
             * Sue Smith
             * Mobiletuts+ Tutorial: Capturing and Cropping an Image with the Android Camera
             * July 2012
             *
             */
            public class ShootAndCropActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

                //keep track of camera capture intent
                final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
                //keep track of cropping intent
                final int PIC_CROP = 2;
                //captured picture uri
                private Uri picUri;

                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    //retrieve a reference to the UI button
                    Button captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
                    //handle button clicks
                    captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
                }

                /**
                 * Click method to handle user pressing button to launch camera
                 */
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {     
                        try {
                            //use standard intent to capture an image
                            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                        }
                        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                            //display an error message
                            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Handle user returning from both capturing and cropping the image
                 */
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
                        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                            //get the Uri for the captured image
                            picUri = data.getData();
                            //carry out the crop operation
                            performCrop();
                        }
                        //user is returning from cropping the image
                        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
                            //get the returned data
                            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                            //get the cropped bitmap
                            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                            //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
                            ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
                            //display the returned cropped image
                            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
                        }
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Helper method to carry out crop operation
                 */
                private void performCrop(){
                    //take care of exceptions
                    try {
                        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
                        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
                        //indicate image type and Uri
                        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
                        //set crop properties
                        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        //indicate aspect of desired crop
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                        //indicate output X and Y
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
                        //retrieve data on return
                        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
                        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);  
                    }
                    //respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
                    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                        //display an error message
                        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

[MAIN.XML]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/intro"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/capture"
        />
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picture"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pic_border" />

    </LinearLayout>
```